# Can't execute Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a Quarkus project that works well with Hibernate and PostgreSQL. I restructured the project to extract the DB logic on a module and import it in the main module. When I do this I get this error when calling the DB

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current Mutiny.Session found
        - no reactive session was found in the Vert.x context and the context was not marked to open a new session lazily
        - a session is opened automatically for JAX-RS resource methods annotated with an HTTP method (@GET, @POST, etc.); inherited annotations are not taken into account
```

I tried with @WithSession and Mutiny.SessionFactory but can't resolve the problem.

Some one faced the same problem ?

Comment: Best to create a minimal reproducible project and push it to GitHub. This way, it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Yes, it could be a bug, but it's also possible that something is not quite right in your restructured project. I would suggest creating a test project that we can run and then open on issue for Quarkus (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues). Not much can be done with the info you've provided